# Copy Row(s) To Outside Sheet Based On Data Validation

Tags: google-sheets

I am new to Google Sheet scripts and attempting to put together something for my business for project management purposes.

On edit, I'm looking to move a row to a new sheet outside the current workbook when a specific name is put in the cell T.

For Example:

- if T says "John" - send the entire row to John's Google Sheet by ID
- if T says "Amy" - send the entire row Amy's Google Sheet by ID
- etc.

You can find an example of the sheet below.

Any and all help is appreciated.

[sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11n8TUEiuLLtbyd6ot5imX0zoAOLforHEBnefnHpoZhs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: if you say sheet you mean different spreadsheet or same spreadsheet just different tab (sheet). also when you say ID you mean ID from URL or ID like your kin of internal ID?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. When I say sheet, I mean a different spreadsheet and when I say ID, I mean ID from a URL. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

basically, this is the scenario: each of you (you, Amy and John) has own spreadsheet. you as "work assigner" have a master sheet with ID: **`11n8TUEiuLLtbyd6ot5imX0zoAOLforHEBnefnHpoZhs`** (from the example you provided in your question) and all your data are in the sheet called **`Sheet1`** dispersed across the range of cells: **A1:AA** (also from the example you provided in your question)...

now go to John's spreadsheet and paste this into cell **A1**:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("11n8TUEiuLLtbyd6ot5imX0zoAOLforHEBnefnHpoZhs", "Sheet1!A1:AA"),
 "select * where Col20='John'", 1)
```

next, go to Amy's spreadsheet and paste this into cell **A1**:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("11n8TUEiuLLtbyd6ot5imX0zoAOLforHEBnefnHpoZhs", "Sheet1!A1:AA"),
 "select * where Col20='Amy'", 1)
```

**note:** your spreadsheet can't be private. set permissions to: **anyone with link can edit/view**

Comment: Hi, I appreciate this response. Do you know of a script to do this? I am aware of the importance function.

Comment: @KeranSmith unfortunately no. but keep in mind that scripted solution would require additional permissions which could complicate few things for not so advanced users

Comment: @KeranSmith if you are affraid that John would "invade" Amy's tasks by force (like changing his name to Amy's name) then you could assign them some digit numbers like Amy: 7834546574665, John: 45646545456445 which you will put them for example in AA column of your sheet and then refere to that column in your importrange formula instead of T column (Col20)